# Unable to boot from Fedora LiveCD

Tags: fedora, boot, live-usb, livecd

So I finally decided to move from Windows to Linux. But before that I have wanted to try Fedora distribution from LiveCD. So I downloaded `Fedora 17` .iso file, unpacked it and then burned on my CD. I rebooted the computer and saw message saying "Select proper boot device" (and yes, I change settings right in `BIOS`). So my next step was creating LiveUSB with help of this [creator](https://fedorahosted.org/liveusb-creator/). I still got the same message, even on my friends computer.

File structure of the LiveUSB (CD) looks like this

- boot
- EFI
- LiveOS
- syslinux
- GPL (file)

Can anybody advice what could possibly be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe .iso file isn't good or maybe you made some mistake before burning it. Try not to unpack .iso file. Just download CDBurnerXP (it is free) or something like that, choose option "Burn ISO image" and program will do everything for you (unpack and burn). 
Give it a try ;)

Comment: Well, this could be the reason for the CD but I also tried to boot it from the USB drive and it didn't work. I doubt this would help (because I used software directly from Fedora to create the LiveUSB)

Comment: Thank you, it was really it, so I am sorry for being a stubborn:)

Comment: No problem, enjoy in good distro ;)

Answer (score 1):

Two ideas:

1. The iso file might be corrupt/broken (also, like cyb3er suggested, you should not unpack the file). Did you verify the integrity of the file via MD5/SHA checksum? The Fedora Project site gives instructions on how to do this: https://fedoraproject.org/en/verify
2. Could you check with a partition editor like GParted whether the partition with the contents of the Live CD/USB has the boot flag set?

Answer (score 0):

On top of what others have suggested above:

Maybe you got a 64bit version for a 32 bit machine or another version incompatible with your hardware. Have you checked this>